# Is there a way to have an SKSpriteNode change images when the mouse is hovering over it?

Tags: macos, hover, mouse, sprite-kit

I've heard that SKScenes inherit from NSResponder, which I guess is why I can use methods like mouseMoved, etc. I'm trying to figure out an easy way to change an image for a SKSpriteNode when the mouse hovers over it. This is for a Cocoa SpriteKit game (NOT iOS).